# How to change default OS at startup

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu 14.01 in Drive E and windows 10.1(preview version) in Drive C, but at start up 
windows is boot up automatically , their is no option for choosing the OS. So how can change the OS at boot up time.?????

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu and then Windows, the Windows bootloader would of overwritten the Ubuntu one, so [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) may help.

Answer (score 0):

install boot loader again with `boot-repair`, it should work.